# How to remove gaps in GridBagLayout?

Tags: java, swing, awt, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I have a GridBagLayout JPanel with some components in it, but there is too much empty space between them.

```
    float wx = 1f, wy = 1f;
    optionsPanel.add(optionsPanelLanguageSelectorInfo,
            new GridBagConstraints(0, 0, 1, 1, wx, wy,
                    GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL,
                    new Insets(0, 100, 0, 10), 0, 0));
    optionsPanel.add(optionsPanelLanguageSelector,
            new GridBagConstraints(1, 0, 1, 1, wx, wy,
                    GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL,
                    new Insets(0, 10, 0, 100), 0, 0));
    optionsPanel.add(optionsPanelAutoSaveToRecentSelectorInfo,
            new GridBagConstraints(0, 1, 1, 1, wx, wy,
                    GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL,
                    new Insets(0, 100, 0, 10), 0, 0));
    optionsPanel.add(optionsPanelAutoSaveToRecentSelector,
            new GridBagConstraints(1, 1, 1, 1, wx, wy,
                    GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL,
                    new Insets(0, 10, 0, 100), 0, 0));
    optionsPanel.add(optionsPanelAutoSecurityCheckSelectorInfo,
            new GridBagConstraints(0, 2, 1, 1, wx, wy,
                    GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL,
                    new Insets(0, 100, 0, 10), 0, 0));
    optionsPanel.add(optionsPanelAutoSecurityCheckSelector,
            new GridBagConstraints(1, 2, 1, 1, wx, wy,
                    GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL,
                    new Insets(0, 10, 0, 100), 0, 0));
```

I tried to change weightx and weighty but no effect. Changing ipadx and ipady didn't help too. I'm new at GridBagLayout so I have no ideas how to fix this issue. **Please help!**

And changing layout manager doensn't fit me too because I'm going to add some more components to my panel.

SOLUTION:
Yes, as I expected the cause was in weightx and weighty values. In my case setting weighty to 0 solved the problem. Hope this would help somebody <3

Comment: The weightx matters here since you are using `GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL` fill constraint, but the weighty does not have an effect since you're not using `GridBagConstraints.BOTH` fill constraint. For more detailed answers, consider creating and posting a valid [mre] in your question. This is not an absolute requirement for getting answers on this site, but can often help expedite things.

Comment: Comment edited as I got weightx/weighty backwards

Comment: have you tried with zero weights? and are you sure the gaps are not in the added components? (assuming you are *not* referring to the gaps produced by the insets)

Answer (score 1):

The empty space between the components is probably caused by the [Insets](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Insets.html). Because thats just what they are used for. From the javadoc:

> An Insets object is a representation of the borders of a container. It specifies the space that a container must leave at each of its edges. The space can be a border, a blank space, or a title.

If you change all entries in the `Insets` to `0` the empty space should be gone:

```
optionsPanel.add(optionsPanelLanguageSelectorInfo,
        new GridBagConstraints(0, 0, 1, 1, wx, wy,
                GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL,
                new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0),//<- important part
                0, 0));
```

Comment: No, the cause is not in this.

Comment: In this case you should edit your question and add a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code, so others can test it. Otherwise we're just guessing.